# How to find a word's page number and font size in PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to search a word in PDF, and I want what page it stays and there the word’s  font size by java code. I use itext so is it possible by itext? If not what library can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to search a word in pdf , and I want what page it stays and there the word’s font size by java code. I use itext so is it possible by itext ?

This is possible using iText. Have a look at the iText 5.5.x `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser` package or the iText 7.0.x kernel `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser` package.

To retrieve the font size, you'll have to extend existing text extraction strategies or create your own from scratch. Inspect the `TextRenderInfo` you get in the strategy callback method to find the font size.

Try this. If you have a tangible problem while implementing that, extend your question accordingly or ask a new one.